# Show Specific DIVs if Selected DIVs are Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle - http://jsbin.com/udumibO/1/edit

If these divs are hidden (they're hidden by the .hide() event handler) then I want two other divs to show.

I tried the following on document.ready, but it's not working, and I have no idea why.

Here's the code.

```
if ($(".select-properties, .div-properties, .image-properties, .table-properties").is(':hidden')) {
    $(".starter-properties, .canvas-properties").show();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do: "Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if **at least one** of these elements matches the given arguments." -- http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: Are you expecting this code to run **when** the other `div`'s get hidden? Why don't you just call `$(".starter-properties, .canvas-properties").show();` right after you call `hide()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish the effect I wanted using the following function.

```
$(".select-tool, .div-tool, .image-tool, .table-tool, .edit-tool").on("mouseup touchend", function() {
  if ($(".select-properties, .div-properties, .image-properties, .table-properties").is(':hidden')) {
    $(".starter-properties, .canvas-properties").show();
    $(".select-properties, .div-properties, .image-properties, .table-properties").hide();
  }
});
```

Here's the fiddle - http://jsbin.com/udumibO/3/edit

I'm sure there's a neater way to write this, but this is the best I could do to accomplish the effect I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if ($('.select-properties, .div-properties, .image-properties, .table-properties').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(".starter-properties, .canvas-properties").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(".target").toggle(function () {
    // your remaining action. something written here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link
It might be helpfull for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsahu/eveKU/

HTML :

```
<div id="first-div">first div</div>
<button id="first">hide above div</button><br/>
<button id="second">show another div when first div is hidden otherwise don't show</button>
<div id="second-div" style="display:none;">Second div</div>
```

JQuery :

```
$("button#first").click(function(){
    $("#first-div").hide();

});
$("button#second").click(function(){

if($('#first-div').is(':visible')) {
    // do nothing
    alert("first div is not hidden");
  }
    else{
         $("#second-div").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like a lot of code here. :P

Great, so I think, you just want to create a tab system and initially you want to hide all the tab content and show something else by default.

Well, Here is something which doing same as your code, and also solving your problem.

```
$("span", ".nav").click(function(){
        var target = $("." + $(this).attr("class").replace(/tool$/g, "properties"));

        target.show().siblings().hide();
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });

    $(".select-properties, .div-properties, .image-properties, .table-properties").hide();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/c7eJh/2/

***JSFiddle code is well commented.***

Let me know, if something you want to add or ask about this. Good luck!